# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK] on Flash builder 4.5.1 when debugging on real device

Tags: android, windows, air, compiler-errors, flash-builder

When I try to debub my `Android 2.2.1` test app on my Samsung galaxy ace GT-S5830 in `Flash builder 4.5.1` I allways get the following error message at 57%, at this time flash builder is trying to install the air runtime.

```
Error occurred while installing the application:
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/Runtime.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]
1839 KB/s (6108444 bytes in 3.242s)
```

Running on desktop emulator works fine.

I'm using a windows 7 machine.

Please help...

Thanks

Comment: May be there is problem of key certificate.

Comment: Actually I think that when debugging directly from flex to the phone, there is no required for the certificate, but I will look into that....

Comment: it's not a problem with the certificate....

Comment: "TheSystem" did you got solution of your problem.

Comment: No, actually the phone can't run air apps, there are some minimum requisites to run them...